# jQuery change html element style with page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have two buttons in a form, I'd like to keep one hidden until the other is clicked. The button that needs to be clicked is a search button and the page needs to refresh in order to show the results (using PHP)
I know absolutely nothing abut jQuery so I googled and took code found on here.

```
    <script>
function showButton() { document.getElementById("b1").style.display = "block";event.preventDefault(); }
</script>
```

Now when the search button is clicked the other button appears but the `event.preventDefault();` prevents the page from loading. Also tried `return:false;` and the same problem happens. How can I allow the page to refresh while also show the button?

If there's a way around that with PHP it would also be great. Thanks.

Comment: use a iframe or ajax

Comment: I have no idea how to go on about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use javascript.  Just pass a  value in a php variable like below

```
$xyz=0;
    if(isset($_POST['search'])){
       $xyz = 1;
    }
```

And in button write inline css with php

```
    If($xyz==1){ echo 'style="display:block;"'; }
else { echo 'style="display:none;"'; }
```

Comment: Worked great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
event.preventDefault();//prevents any post back
```

if you have post back in your page remove this line of code

Comment: When I do that, the button appears for a split second then re disappears. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah you are right,its because of refreshing page,
for preventing this problem you should there are several answers:
     1.you can use ajax request to server an when it done change the 
        visibilty
     2.manage the value of visibiilty in server side
     3.right value in cookie and read from there
     4.add the visibility to url and read each time in page 
and etx

Comment: Yeah you're correct, because of refreshing the page.
You're proposing great solutions, but I've solved the issue with PHP. Check @Suresh Maurya 's answer. Thanks for your time =)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ajax? That would accomplish what you want with out doing a refresh. Look as ajax with the onsuccess event handler to show the button. [See here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)
Unless there is a mission critical reason that the page must refresh. I know some users (depending on the purpose of the form) that do not like the page to refresh just to show a button.

Comment: I haven't tried Ajax no, and I honestly don't know how to. 
Like I mentioned in the question the page needs to refresh in order for the search's results to load. Anyway @Suresh Maurya proposed a great solution. Thanks for your response =)